# Unable to bypass proxy while connecting to Azure CosmosDB from IntelliJ using scala

Tags: scala, azure, intellij-idea, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to connect to azure cosmos DB from intelliJ using scala language.

I am able to fetch the data from DB when I am connecting my laptop from home network. But I am getting timeout error when I connect the laptop from office network. It seems like some proxy issue, So that I have configured the proxy settings in intelliJ as shown below.

[image]

I tried to test my connection from proxy settings page, but it is throwing error as below.

```
Problem with connection: Request failed with status code 401
```

I tried to open the same from browser and received below error.

```
{"code":"Unauthorized","message":"Required Header authorization is missing. Ensure a valid Authorization token is passed.\r\nActivityId: af2d771f-25a3-494a-90dd-b33cd66104e2, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1"}
```

Below is the intelliJ code I tried and this code works.

```
mport org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

object DeleteData {
  /* Get the logger */
  val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("DeleteData").getOrCreate()

    // Configure connection to your collection
    val readConfig = Config(Map(
      "Endpoint" -> "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/",
      "Masterkey" -> "***",
      "Database" -> "ConnectivityDB",
      "Collection" -> "historicData",
      "ConnectionMode" -> "Gateway",
      "SamplingRatio" -> "1.0",
      "query_custom" -> "SELECT c.NUM from c where c._ts = 1564566440"
    ))
    // Connect via azure-cosmosdb-spark to create Spark DataFrame
    val docs = spark.read.cosmosDB(readConfig)
    println("Total Count: " +docs.count())
    docs.show(5)

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Is there any way to bypass the proxy for getting connected to cosmos DB from intelliJ ?

Comment: Please do not show your private info in the public forum,that's huge risk for you.Even though i have edited that for you already, you'd better re-generate your primary key.

Comment: @JayGong Thank you :)  even the endpoint and primary key provided by me were not exact values.  Going forward i ll take care of hiding private info.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the IntelliJ proxy setting doesn't affect your code,you could try to catch the request by Fiddler tool.

Maybe you could set the proxy setting in the code.Please see this [link](http://techs.studyhorror.com/scala-proxy-authentication-i-184).

```
import java.net.Authenticator
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication

class ProxyAuthenticator(user: String, password: String) extends Authenticator {

  def this() = this("default_user_name", "default_password")

  override def getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication = {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
  }
}
```

Comment: Intellij IDEA proxy settings are for IDE internal network services, like Plugins Market, or updates.

Comment: @jay Gong: Above solution is not working.. Even I tried this  

`val connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
    connectionPolicy.setProxy("proxyhost", portnum)`
But not working

Comment: @Antony Still met the same issue?

Comment: yes. Even after setting proxy in code also i am facing the same issue.